# Kotlin lambda with explicit return type

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I have the following Kotlin classes:

```
sealed class Result {
  data class Success()
  data class Failure()
}

class Single<R>(val value: R?, throwable: Throwable?) {
  fun map(mapper: (R) -> T): Single<T> {
    return Single(mapper(value!!), null)
  }
  fun onError(recover: (Throwable) -> T): Single<T> {
    return Single(recover(throwable!!))
  }
}
```

And I have the following function:

```
fun handle(single: Single<String>): Single<Result> {
  return single
    .map { Single.Success() }
    .onError { Single.Error() }
}
```

But `onError` fails with:

```
Type Mismatch.
  Required: Single.Success
  Found:    Single.Error
```

I realize I can work around this with:

```
fun handle(single: Single<String>): Single<Result> {
  return single
    .map { Single.Success() as Single<Result> }
    .onError { Single.Error() as Single<Result> }
}
```

But I prefer to force type inference to work left-to-right as much as possible. That is, I'd prefer the `{ Single.Success() }` lambda to specify and explicit return type.

Is an explicit return type allowed in Kotlin? the [functionLiteral Grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#functionLiteral) makes it look like it can't, but I'm not an expert in reading grammars.

Comment: Does adding `in` do anything for you?

```
fun handle(single: Single<String>): Single<in Result> {
        return single
                .map { Result.Success() }
                .onError { Result.Failure() }
    }
```

Comment: I can't alter `handle`, so no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You actually cannot explicitly declare the return type in a Kotlin lambda:

> One thing missing from the lambda expression syntax presented above is the ability to specify the return type of the function.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions

Answer (score 9):

This worked! Someone else gave me the answer in another forum, and if they respond here, I'll mark their answer correct.

```
fun handle(single: Single<String>): Single<Result> {
  return single
    .map<Result> { Single.Success() }
    .onError<Result> { Single.Error() }
}
```

Comment: Marked gutenmorgenuhu's answer as correct because they gave a direct link to the docs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56311548/9636